# How could I redirect in bind to another host in case server 1 went down?

Tags: dns, redirection, forwarding, bind

I have two servers with same service, so

```
server 1 xxx.myhost.com   A record ip 1.1.1.1
server 2 xx2.myhost.com   CNAME record to otherhost.com
```

The server number 1 is the principal, so, I gave to my clients this host (xxx.myhost.com) to get access.
Server 2 is a supporting server, in case #1 is not working.

I want to know: supposing server 1 went down for any reason,
how should I configure bind to redirect to server 2?

so graphically  my client call xxx.myhost.com ----it's down--- so bind automatically redirect to----xx2.myhost.com.

And of course my clients don't know about server 2 and they don't need to know it...

It's like MX servers ...only with A and CNAME records....

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is *failover*. This has actually been [covered more technically over on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/495124/a-record-failover). But the tl;dr version is that Bind has no native facility for this.

You could use [DDNS and zone updates](http://www.linux-faqs.info/dns/failover-dynamic-dns-bind-and-dhcp) to achieve this, but that would require quite a bit of additional configuration.

I guess you could also set up a custom script to monitor the server and push a zone update when it goes down. But again, quite a bit of custom configuration there. And it would be subject to the same problems mentioned in the first link - namely DNS caching.

As Rex said in the first link, some DNS providers, such as Route53 (which I have personal experience with) have integrated failover capability. This is probably the most 'sane' implementation.

A more exotic option is to set up the DNS to point to a 'gateway' server, which has static routes pointing to the 'preferred' server. A daemon of some type can check if the server is alive and change the routes as needed. This wouldn't have DNS latency, but - again - this is a pretty custom setup.

Links:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/495124/a-record-failover
- http://www.linux-faqs.info/dns/failover-dynamic-dns-bind-and-dhcp